# Network mapping for all users & Windows System error 86

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2016, network-drive

I want to map a network drive for all users of a VM running windows server 2016.
To do this I created a .bat file with the following code:

```
 net use T: \\IP adress\share /user:AccountName Password /persistent:yes
```

and ran it in cmd as admin.
At first it worked. I was able to access the drive. However, upon signing in and out of my account to check that it would keep the connection, the account was locked.

I unlocked the account and tried again to which I got the following error:

"*System error 86 has occurred.
The specified network password is not correct.*"

However the account is open and I can use it for other things still.

For some reason I am unable to disconnect the drive, not sure if this is helpful but wanted to give all the information I have

Comment: The root causes are the same as in https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/storage-scale/4.2.2?topic=si-smb-client-linux-fails-nt-status-logon-failure